# I want a query to get LIST of averages of users in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the list of averages from a table who has the list of users

Not single average but a list

```
select avg(no_of_interactions) from table name;
```

where I want to get the list of avg interactions of `{user1,user2,user3}` so on

it is giving me only one average

Comment: `SELECT user, avg(no_of_interactions) FROM table GROUP BY user`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
select <column>, avg(no_of_interactions)
from table <name>
group by <column>;
```

where `<column>` is userName or userId or anything else you want to use as grouping condition

Comment: 101
101
101
101
101
102
102
102
102
102
102
102
102
102
102
102

Comment: user_id:101 and user_id:102

Comment: user_id:101 and user_id:102,103,etc interaction average should be found and list of avg should be displayed